# Garbage collection of local variables inside a static function

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have written below ETL function in Java which is invoked with 1000-2000 events every minute and returns the events which have been loaded successfully (for some check-pointing purpose):

```
public static Event[] loadEvents(Event[] events) {
    List<ITuple> persistedEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
    List<DestinationMessage> destinationMessages = convertToDestinationFormat(events);
    loader.send(destinationMessages); // Synchronous persistence call
    for (Event event : events) {
        persistedEvents.add(event);
    }
    return persistedEvents.toArray(new Event[persistedEvents.size()]);
}

private static List<DestinationMessage> convertTuplesToKafkaMessages(Event[] events) {
        List<DestinationMessage> destinationMessages = new ArrayList<DestinationMessage>();
        for (Event event : events) {
            DestinationMessage destinationMessage = new DestinationMessage();
            destinationMessage.setData(event.getData());
            destinationMessages.add(destinationMessage);
        }
    return destinationMessages;
}
```

If the functions where non-static I am sure there is no memory leak, but I want to understand if it makes any difference in case functions are static as above?

I believe it should not as the objects are instantiated inside the function call so they should get garbage collected every time the function call gets over (and depending on when garbage collector actually does it).

I am facing heap space issue on my machine and just wondering if this function could be the culprit. Memory usage keeps on increasing from `6GB` to `16GB` (available memory).

Could someone please point out memory leak, if any. Do I need to set `destinationMessages` to `NULL` at the end of `loadEvents`?

Comment: You can't know when the objects you create get collected by the GC; it runs on it's own, when it feels it should

Comment: eclipse MAT is a great tool to find your memory leak https://eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: @Vince Emigh this is partially true. If you are keeping track of memory size using `Runtime's` functionality, you can definitely witness the results of garbage collection. But of course that doesn't nessessarily mean that a particular object that was eligible for garbage collection was actually disposed.

Comment: As far as I know Phantom references could be helpfull in checking whether object was garbage collected or not.

Comment: That is right and I have no issues with that. But the only thing I am concerned about is if there is any memory leak in my code. Could garbage collector behave so bad to not do garbage collection till I lose my 10GB of RAM (6 to 16GB) in 8 hours?

Comment: Instead of creating the ArrayList and then invoking toArray, have you tried copying the array directly (using java.util.Arrays.copyOf())? That would avoid having to GC the ArrayList instances.

Comment: You are returning sth from those methods. If you will assign those results somewhere GC will nor remove them from heap as long as there will be strong reference to them

Comment: @JohnnyAW: I am running it as a binary. I don't think eclipse MAT would help there?

Comment: @AndyTurner: List is only keeping references to the array objects right? So I doubt that it is causing the trouble. Plus it is entitled to garbage collection anyways. One list object created once a minute should not be a big deal.

Comment: The ArrayList has to store those references though, and the space it uses for storage has to be reclaimed. It's basically just another array with a bit of wrapping.

Comment: But that is instantiated locally so should get reclaimed by garbage collector in some time. And the method in actuality is not that simple, it is preparing chunks of events and sending to persisted store in a no. of calls. ArrayList keeps on adding persisted events to itself and ignores events which failed to persist. Finally only persisted events are sent back in an array. I had hidden those details to simplify the problem.

Comment: @abhishek08aug if you can generate a memory dump, you can open it in MAT. You can configure java to create memory dump on OutOfMemory

Answer (score 1):

Static fields are associated with the class, not an individual instance.

Static fields are cleaned up when the ClassLoader which hold the class unloaded. In many simple programs, that is never.

If you want the fields to be associated with an instances and cleaned up then the instance is cleaned up, make them instance fields, not static ones.

Comment: Now you have confused me in a totally different direction. Are not static fields and local objects inside a static function diifferent? Please notice that I am not using any static field here but just a static function with local objects.

Comment: Who all support static field argument in my code context?

Comment: @Magnamag: What do you mean by "OP's"?

Comment: @abhishek08aug That's you! See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op)

Comment: OoPs :) I din't know that

Comment: Here static field means anything static variable or static method as well. That will be always associated with the class not with any particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your facts quite right in terms of garbage collection

In Java (or C, or C++) there are functionally 3 kinds of memory: System mem (ignore), stack and heap. Stack memory is automatically cleared when a function returns. The only memory that needs to be collected is memory that's allocated in the heap, and this only happens when garbage collection (gc) runs.

This has nothing to do with static / non-static context.

If you are having memory issues, you might want to create a counter that counts how many times your method has been called, and explicitly call `System.gc();` after a set number of runs

Comment: Never call `System.gc();`, as you cant be sure if it'll actually trigger GC, since it's just a request (which can be ignored). If anything, adjust the heap and size your spaces (edan and survivors) to fit your application. I suggest running through it with a profiler, if anything; find the source of the problem (if there is one)

Comment: I know I am overthinking to find out something which is taking all my memory away and smashing my brain out :(

Comment: @abhishek08aug Have you tried profiling your application? Go get a free trial of JProfiler real quick and profile your application (the tool is really easy to use). There are ways of finding what is exhausting resources (taking too much mem), and profiling your application is a real easy way to find out what'a causing your problems. Come back when you find the source and can't figure out how to resolve it